# TypeError: Guild._add_role() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a role to myself using user id and role id, but am constantly getting an error.

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(1053022209087656026)
    await guild._add_role(487228854084304898, 1053027595056336997)
```

```
File "/home/osass/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osass/Documents/Python/Ppl in irl bot.py", line 9, in on_ready
    await guild._add_role(487228854084304898, 1053027595056336997)
TypeError: Guild._add_role() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I've only written the user id and role id, why is the error saying I've taken three positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [this method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) to add a role to a member.

For exemple:

```py
member = guild.get_member(user_id)
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: After adding these three lines of code after the guild fetch and running, i get the error:
File "/home/osass/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osass/Documents/Python/Ppl in irl bot.py", line 11, in on_ready
    await member.add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Comment: Is the intents member activated on your bot? This is a necessary condition for `Guild.get_member` to work. If it is not enabled and you are able to do it, enable it. Otherwise, use this method :https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member.